# Regarding Sony’s Lifelog API close down

Tags: sony, sony-lifelog-api

As, Sony’s Lifelog API was closed down at the end of May 2017. Does there exist any alternative for a developer, meanwhile?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not a publicly available SDK for accessing the data directly.

Comment: Datasheet for Swr12 is not public either, is it?

Comment: What information are you looking for exactly. You should be able to find all available information on the device here : https://www.sonymobile.com/us/products/smart-products/smartband-2/specifications/#tabs

Answer (score -2):

You should actually be able to use the Google Fit API to pull fitness data for your needs. You can even use it to pull heart rate data from the SmartBand 2.

https://developers.google.com/fit/

Comment: That's an entirely different API, which has nothing to do with Sony Lifelog. I don't think this is what the OP is after (I came looking for the actual Sony API as well)

Comment: unfortunately the Sony Lifelog API is completely shutdown at this point with no way to access it.

Comment: what if we want to get data directly from swr12 accelerometer ?Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Unfortunately this is also not possible with the swr12 as their is no publicly available api to pul the data directly from the device.