# How to download Sony Lifelog Sleep data?

Tags: google-fit, sony-lifelog-api

Now that the Sony LifeLog API is [shut down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604451/regarding-sony-s-lifelog-api-close-down/44817499#44817499), I'm trying to figure out how to get access to my sleep data (e.g. daily hours slept, wake up time, bedtime).

---

In the [OAuth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground), I tried sending queries to Google Fit for Sony Data, but I'm getting back an empty `point` array no matter what I try.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/raw:com.google.activity.segment:com.sonymobile.hostapp.everest:Sony Mobile Communications Inc.:SWR12:24234b96:/datasets/1397513334728708316-1504711909728708316
```

(This date range should be from [April 14, 2014](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1397513334728708316%20ns%20%2B%20january%201%201970) until today.)

---

I tried with the other datasources I found, `raw:com.google.heart_rate.bpm:com.sonymobile.hostapp.everest:Sony Mobile Communications Inc.:SWR12:24234b96:` or `raw:com.google.step_count.delta:com.sonymobile.hostapp.everest:Sony Mobile Communications Inc.:SWR12:24234b96:`, but those both returned empty data as well.

Even though these `sonymobile` datasources are return from `https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataSources/list`, when I query them directly I get a 404:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/raw:com.google.activity.segment:com.sonymobile.hostapp.everest:Sony Mobile Communications Inc.:SWR12:24234b96:
```

(I can see other dataSources are valid though by requesting e.g. `https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps`)

---

How can I get download my sleep data for the last year?

Comment: Unfortunately with Lifelog being shutdown you will not be able to pull any data at all from the system. Also Lifelog data is not connected to data from Google fit so you would not be able to access it this way. At this point there is no way to access any data from the Lifelog API.